# Why two almost idetical grep commands return different output: w/o and with filename

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression, glob

I have 2 almost identical `grep`s:

```
[Alex@localhost tmp]$ grep /bin/bash /etc/passwd 
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
AlexL:x:500:500::/home/AlexL:/bin/bash
user1:x:501:501:user1 12345:/home/user1:/bin/bash
```

vs.

```
[AlexL@localhost tmp]$ grep /bin/*sh /etc/passwd    
/etc/passwd:root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
/etc/passwd:AlexL:x:500:500::/home/AlexL:/bin/bash
/etc/passwd:user1:x:501:501:user1 12345:/home/user1:/bin/bash
```

In 2nd query I got filename prefix for every line match.
I know that to get the same result I need to put `-h` option in 2nd `grep`, but my question is:

**Why do they return different output?**
Should I add something more?

The task consist of retrieving from `/etc/passwd` real users (w/o daemons and system users).

Used: CentOS 6.4, grep gnu 2.6.3 version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your shell expands `/bin/*sh`. So, what you are really doing is

```
grep /bin/bash /bin/dash /bin/rbash /bin/rzsh /bin/sh /bin/zsh /etc/passwd
```

That is, search for the string `/bin/bash` in the files `/bin/dash`, `/bin/rbash`, `/bin/rzsh`, `/bin/sh`, `/bin/zsh` and `/etc/passwd`.

(Compare with the output of `echo /bin/*sh /etc/passwd`.)

Since there are several files to search in, `grep` reports which one it found the string in.

What you want is to quote your search term, so it isn't expanded by the shell, and to use a proper regular expression:

```
grep '/bin/.*sh' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! 
before this I've tried `'/bin/*sh'` - doesn't work. I forgot a little but RegExps.. forgot to add dot (any char) `.*` (once, none or many).